# Problems with sending json data to telegram bot node js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, telegram-bot

I am really having this strange thing going on in my code. So, I am getting data from the db and then extract the data and send the data back to the bot. Everything works great so far but here is the real issue. While sending the data from the json array, I see that the data is sent in a random order from the array and not sequentially as I expected. What could be the reason for that? and How do i solve it?

```
case 'summary':
var balance = "";
var transactionsummary = "";
var date = "";
flag = 0;
trx.getsummary(senderid).then(function (v) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(v);

    if (obj.balance2 != '-1') {
        console.log("Entered");

        balance = obj.balance2;
        transactionsummary = obj.transactionsummary;
        date = obj.date2;

        flag = flag + 1;

    }

    if (flag > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < balance.length; i++) {
            console.log(i, balance[i]);
            telegram.sendMessage(senderid, "Balance" + "||" + balance[i] + "||" + "transactionsummary" +
                "||" + transactionsummary[i] + "date" + "||" + date[i]);

        }

        console.log(balance);

        telegram.answerCallbackQuery(msg.id);
        flag = 0;
    } else {
        telegram.sendMessage(senderid, "Your telegram ID is not registered,Kindly contact your bank");
        telegram.answerCallbackQuery(msg.id);
    }
});
break;

//When I logged the balance, I get the data in this order [5000,3000,1500] which is correct.
```

The response I am getting in the bot sends the data in random order. And I really dont want that as it changes the whole meaning of transaction summary.

Comment: JSON is not meant to be parsed line by line. If you need order, you can add an addtional field like `seq_no` to your JSON.